# Stream Video in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a table view with some movies:

[image]

When i select row from a table i do this:

Found movie for example is:

h t tp://.../movies/video/Adventure (Low-360p).mp4

```
NSString *URL = [foundMovie.movie stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[mp setFullscreen:YES];

[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];

[mp prepareToPlay];
[mp play];
```

**There is no error - nothing happens...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[mp prepareToPlay];
mp.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[mp setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
 mp.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL];
mp.controlStyle = YES;
  mp.fullscreen = YES;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish1:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

 [mp play];
```

Comment: Ok, now i hear the movie, but i still dont see it

Comment: Still don't see. And it stops after 5 sec

Comment: can u play that url in Chrome ??

Comment: I will edit my answer again with full code , you try with that.
I will double check, it will work in my device.. OK ?

Comment: and another thing that sometimes it plays, sometimes it crashes. And if plays than only about 3 seconds

Comment: Your last code now really works... it plays all the movie, but there is only sound - player doesn't show up on top of my app.

Comment: that's bit strange..anyway add subview on keywindow.  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:mp];

Comment: With your code app fails 2013-10-24 08:37:18.942 Pasakas[491:a0b] -[MPMoviePlayerController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc049360
With this - only audio
[self.view addSubview:[mp view]];

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project uses ARC, your code does not retain the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance. As a consequence, the player goes away almost immediately.

Try changing the local variable `mp` to be a property of your view-controller. That way the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance will be retained for the life of the view-controller.

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *mp;
@end

// ....

self.mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that player doesn't show up:

```
// frame must match parent view!!!!!!!!!
[[mp view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
[self.view addSubview: [mp view]];
```

Comment: This is bit strange, 
Actually no need to add the subview itself. If you make mp.fullscreen = YES; and [mp play]; , it should work..have you tried this ?  Anyway glad to know its working.